How to put a logo below the sidebar in a quarto book?
I would like to build a png-image below the sidebar on the right in a quarto-book:

I have tried to find a solution with the help of ChatGPT. Unfortunately not successful. So I don't have a solution. But here is my code:
index.qmd:
# Preface {.unnumbered}

This is a Quarto book.

To learn more about Quarto books visit <https://quarto.org/docs/books>.

_quarto.yml:
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "q_book_exampl"
  author: "Norah Jones"
  date: "2.7.2024"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd 
format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo 


Here is the test image:


You could do it like this: A logo can be used in the sidebar by configuring _quarto.yml as described here in the documentation. Additionally we add a small EventListener which applies appendChild in order to relocate the image below the content of the sidebar.

_quarto.yml:
project:
  type: book

book:
  title: "q_book_exampl"
  author: "Norah Jones"
  date: "2.7.2024"
  chapters:
    - index.qmd
  sidebar:
    logo: 'testImage.png'

format:
  html:
    theme: cosmo 
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        <script>
          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            var sidebar = document.getElementById('quarto-sidebar');
            var logo = sidebar.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
            
            sidebar.appendChild(logo);
          });
        </script>


Thank you very much! A follow-up question: Is it also possible to place the logo at the top of the sidebar at the same time, i.e. via "q_book_example"? So that there are two logos in the sidebar at the end?

Yes, this is possible, in the JS above, instead use var logo = sidebar.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].cloneNode();. Then there will also be the logo at the top of the sidebar, where it is as defined by sidebar: logo: ....
